# The best way to reference different version of DLLs and generate Dll with different version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, autocad-plugin

I am working on an AutoCAD add-in project, which will ref AutoCAD dll. One of the challenges is that we have different CAD versions on our laptops. So I have different solutions named in different versions so each solution can reference its related DLLs during the development.

For example:

1. Laptop 1 with AutoCAD 2018
2. Laptop 2 with AutoCAD 2019

Build two solutions named AutoCAD Plug-in 2018 and AutoCAD Plug-in 2019. Both of them are refering to different versions of AutoCAD dll. However, the code is pretty much the same way.

It doesn't bother me to refer to different DLLs because the DLL would not copy to the solution folder(AutoCAD requires that). It would use whatever version is in the AutoCAD folder. For example, I have AutoCAD 2018 installed at `C:\Program`. When AutoCAD loads a plug-in dll, the plug-in dll will use any related dll that is the same in the AutoCAD folder.

I desire to have one solution, that refers to different versions of dlls, and when you build the solution, you will compile the solution into different plug-ins with different version names.

So for example, Visual Studio would generate two dlls:

1. AutoCAD plug-in 2018
2. AutoCAD plug-in 2019

So that I don't need to maintain the same code in different solutions.

Would be possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are having same situation with me. What I did was using the Post Build/Pre Build Events to copy the DLL version that I need to the output folders
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2022

Example:

```
echo $(ConfigurationName)

if "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Release" (copy $(SolutionDir)\dlls\file1.dll $(SolutionDir)bin\x86\Release\file1.dll)
if "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Any" (copy $(SolutionDir)\dlls\file2.dll $(SolutionDir)bin\x86\Release\file1.dll)
```

In addition, you can create a custom build batch file (.bat). I haven't tried this one but I see other projects using it to create builds for Fortify code-scan request.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/specifying-custom-build-events-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022